# Bypass MapBox 500KB Individual Tile Size Limit?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mbtiles

Does anybody know how to bypass MapBox's 500KB tile size limit?

The rule from [their website](https://www.mapbox.com/help/source-manual/#size-limits) states: "Individual vector tiles can not exceed 500kb at any zoom level."

I am hitting this limit with a set of data at a few zoom levels. (I create this data in .mbtiles format by running a geojson file through tippecanoe.) I tried uploading through their Uploads API, but that still has the limit. Removing features and working at lower detail levels are not options. I've also tried emailing MapBox, but I have not heard anything.

Answer (score 5):

The only way to get around the limit while using Mapbox's infrastructure is to break the data up into several different tilesets, all of which are used by your layer.

If you're self-hosting, then you can use Tippecanoe's `--maximum-tile-bytes=` option to set whatever tile size limit you want.

Answer (score 1):

As [explained](https://www.mapbox.com/help/source-manual/#size-limits) by Mapbox, keeping the tiles bellow 500 KB ensures fast rendering . I believe it also allows for optimizations in their cloud infrastructure.

If self-hosting is an option, you can host larger tiles using a map server such as [tessera](https://github.com/mojodna/tessera), [tilehut](https://github.com/b-g/tilehut) or [Chubbs Spatial Server](https://github.com/spatialdev/PGRestAPI)

To serve an .mbtiles file with tessera, you can run:

```
tessera mbtiles://./dataset.mbtiles
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the

```
--no-tile-size-limit
```

flag, equivalent to `-pk`. Source: "[Setting or disabling tile size limits](https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe#setting-or-disabling-tile-size-limits)" section of the [documentation](https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe).

You might as well might be interested in `--no-feature-limit` or `-pf`, which removes the 200k features/tile limit.